# Uploading images with AJAX torest framework

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I want to upload images to my Django app using drf and AJAX
I don't have a model to do I just want to serialize data

Here is serializers.py

```
first_name = serializers.CharField()
last_name = serializers.CharField()
password1 = serializers.CharField()
password2 = serializers.CharField()
prof_img = serializers.ImageField()
bio = serializers.CharField()
email = serializers.EmailField()
```

This is views.py

@api_view (['POST'])
def register_api (request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
return redirect ('/')

```
print('register_api')
# print(request.data)
serialized = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
print('hi')
if serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    print('valid')
    print('data -> ', serialized.data)
    return
print('invalid')
```

I just want to print data, everything gets serilized but shows prof_img = {}

This is my function from where I am sending data

```js
async function register_form_submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var formElm = event.target
  const myFormData = Object.values(event.target).reduce((obj, field) => {
    obj[field.name] = field.value;
    return obj
  }, {})
  console.log(myFormData)
  myFormData.prof_img = imgElm.files[0]
  console.log('new -> ', myFormData)

  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
      myFormData
    )
  }
  const resp = await fetch('/accounts/register_api', options)
  console.log(resp)
  console.log(resp.message)
  console.log(resp.status)
}
```

I tried removing
`"Content-Type": "application/json",`

But then Python console showed
`Unsupported Media Type: /accounts/register_api`

This is my snipped from settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES,
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
)
}
```

Please try to avoid class based serializers or class based views

Comment: I observed that you try send file without using FormData Object. If you need send file as string using JSON, may you need use FileReader to get Base64 string of the image.

Comment: FormData didn't worked I used var mydata = new FormData(element) but it shows nothing

Comment: You tried with With FileReader API ?

Comment: FormData() require diferent configuration fetch.

Comment: I don't know abt fileReader api can u plz explain more abt it

Comment: Yes i will add example..

Answer (score 1):

This send file in BASE64 string via JSON. I your server PY you need decode base64 to get the binay file.

```
          async function register_form_submit(event) {
                event.preventDefault()
                var formElm = event.target
                const myFormData = Object.values(event.target).reduce((obj, field) => {
                    obj[field.name] = field.value;
                    return obj
                }, {});


                const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
                        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
                    });
                    
                    await toBase64(formElm.files[0]).then(base64=>{
                         myFormData.prof_img = base64;
                    }).error(error=>{
                        //MANAGE ERROR HERE.
                        myFormData.prof_img="";
                        return;
                    });
                const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(
                            myFormData
                            )
                }
                const resp = await fetch('/accounts/register_api', options)
                console.log(resp)
                console.log(resp.message)
                console.log(resp.status)
            }
```

Comment: U=Image gets converted into base64 and formdata =>   `prof_img: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD"` but server still says `Unsupported Media Type: /accounts/register_api`. on printing request.data

Comment: add in header: > 'Accept': 'application/json',

Comment: In your server side python: remove data:image/jpeg;base64, from base64 string before decode it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415